# UserForm preventing file to be opened (VBA)

Tags: vba, file, userform, explorer

I tried to find the solution but with no success until now.

I created an UserForm where user can click each button on it, and a file explorer will be opened up. But, I can't open the file inside that file explorer UNLESS the UserFrom is closed. But I want the UserForm to be there all the time.

Any suggestion and idea is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use a [modeless](https://www.teachexcel.com/excel-tutorial/2029/modeless-userform) userform

Comment: Hi @PeterT, that is really great. Thank you. I did not expect the solution is just so simple. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this:

1. Change the ShowModal option from True to False
2. With code: UserForm1.Show vbModeless